# Overlapping cells-content

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

recently I discovered a really annoying bug:

the content of two cells (the first cell in the table and the last cell in the table) are mixed up in one cell (in the first and the last cell of the table). This only occurs if I habe 10 entries in my table and add an 11th (see picture).

Do you have any idea how such a behavior can occur?

Regards,
Sascha

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9fkj.jpg]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

static NSString *kCellTextField_ID = @"CellTextField_ID";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID];
if (cell == nil)
{
// a new cell needs to be created
cell = [[[UITableViewCellGradient alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID] autorelease];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
else
{
// a cell is being recycled, remove the old edit field (if it contains one of our tagged edit fields)
UIView *viewToCheck = nil;
viewToCheck = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
if (!viewToCheck) {
    [viewToCheck removeFromSuperview];
}
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

id objId = [[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:kViewKey];

if ([objId isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
    UITextField *textField = [[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
} else if ([objId isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedField = [[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedField];
}
} 

if (row == 0) {
[cell setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionTop];
} else if (row == ([data count] - 1)) {
[cell setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionBottom];
} else {
[cell setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle];
}



return cell;}
```

Comment: Looks like undefined behavior caused by an incorrect implementation of the UITableViewSourceDelegate on your side. (The caching of cells can be quite complicated)

Can you show us some code?

Comment: If you could post the code, please. I hade something similar once and it turned out I did it wrong in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: You should update your Question with the code in your "Answer" and delete the "Answer".  What tag value do the textField and segmentedField have?  Are you sure they are being removed when the cell is recycled?

Comment: What tag value do the textField and segmentedField have? Are you sure they are being removed when the cell is recycled?

Comment: Is it possible to delete my answer? The textField has the tag value "1". I'm not sure what do you mean by segmentedField? The textFields are being removed when the cell is recycled ([viewToCheck removeFromSuperview];).

Comment: (There should be a Delete link to the lower-left of your answer.  If not perhaps it requires enough rep.)  You are adding a control called "segmentedField" as well as "textField".  How have you verified the tag and the removal?  Put NSLogs to confirm what you think is happening is actually happening.  Make sure when the controls are added to contentView that their tag is set to 1.  Make sure the removeFromSuperview is being called for both of them.

Comment: OK, I see, well, I think, I don't have enough rep :-) Well in this view I don't use segmentedField. This is a general implementation of the method and can be used for textFields and segmented controls. Actually, I recently noticed, the textField aren't removed from superview, I think, I'll have to investigate this.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was a stupid error with the tag deletion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

static NSString *kCellTextField_ID = @"CellTextField_ID";
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID];
if (cell == nil)
{
    // a new cell needs to be created
    cell = [[[UITableViewCellGradient alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellTextField_ID] autorelease];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
else
{
    // a cell is being recycled, remove the old edit field (if it contains one of our tagged edit fields)
    UIView *viewToCheck = nil;
    viewToCheck = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    if (!viewToCheck) {
        [viewToCheck removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

if (indexPath.section == 0) {

    id objId = [[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:kViewKey];

    if ([objId isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = [[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    } else if ([objId isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
        UISegmentedControl *segmentedField = [[self.data objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:kViewKey];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedField];
    }
} 

if (row == 0) {
    [cell setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionTop];
} else if (row == ([data count] - 1)) {
    [cell setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionBottom];
} else {
    [cell setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle];
}



return cell;}
```